# Windows 10 Mail App can receive mail but can't send it

Tags: windows-10, email

I am trying to use the Windows 10 Mail App to send/receive email using my work email account.  I am able to successfully receive email but everytime I tried to send a new email, it goes straight to the Outbox and never gets sent.

When I received email initially, I had to accept a certificate.  I haven't been prompted to accept a certificate with sending but I suspect that is the hang up.

How can I get the Mail App to send emails?

Answer (score 3):

Doing a refresh ("Sync this view") on the Sent Items page prompted the certificate download and now I can send mail.